# Passing an instance of a FB into the initialization of a different instance from a different function block

Tags: oop, plc, twincat, structured-text, twincat-hmi

I am new to twincat3 and especially using it with oop.
I am trying to pass an instance of FB_EventLogger to the FB_init of an instance of O2_Sensor.
Forexample:
Main
Var
EventLogger : FB_EventLogger (I_PersistantEventStrotagr := CSV);
O2_sensor   : O2_Sensor(EventLogger := EventLogger);
end_var

end_Main

O2_Sensor
var
EventLogger : Reference to FB_EventLogger ;
eventinfo : something;
end_var

method_addEvent

Eventlogger.AddEvent(eventinfo);
end_method_addEvent

end_O2_Sensor

I would like to allow for any instance of the O2_sensor FB to be able to create their own event as this will make the code much better rather than having a seperate function that checks all the different inputs and then raises alarms or sents messages.

The First thing I thought about was to pass the instance of eventlogger fb and use that in the sensor's fb but that does not work. However, it works if I create a method that takes in a reference to an event logger, in other words O2_Sensor.addevent(EventLogger).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unable to fully understand your attempt reading your question. Initialization can be very tricky. Here are a few pointers :

- The FB_Init of en enclosing function block instance is called after the FB_Init of nested function blocks it contains. You cannot pass as an argument to the FB_Init of a nested function block anything that is set by the enclosing function block's own FB_Init.
- However, when using inheritance, if CHILD_FB extends PARENT_FB, then variables assigned in PARENT_FB.FB_Init can be used as arguments to the nested function blocks of CHILD_FB. You can therefore go around the limitation by introducing a level of inheritance. A bit more code, but it is easy code to write, and saves worse ugliness elsewhere.
- Please note that you can use the "THIS" pointer as an argument to embedded function block instances, and the pointer is valid at the time the embedded instance's FB_Init is called. The pointer is valid (and can be used for reference injection), but calling methods on it is not intrinsically guaranteed to work (see next point).
- Because you can receive a valid reference (or pointer) to an instance does not mean you can execute arbitrary methods on it, because those methods may rely on something that is not ready yet. It does not mean it cannot work either : the code can be called, and "plain" variables (i.e. not function blocks) and (potentially nested) arrays/structures of plain variables are usable.
- I make heavy use of reference injection, I use FB_Init for assignments (including reference assignments), but not to call methods, unless I know those methods use only plain variables or structures of the same instance. This makes FB_Init independent of initialization order (very important for me, your mileage may vary).
- Due to when/how FB_Init is executed, you cannot step into code it contains or calls. Bugs in FB_Init are therefore very difficult to debug, and doing only simple things helps avoid frustrating debugging sessions.
- You may need, or benefit from, an initialization mechanism separate from FB_Init to finish the job. I have a whole framework that manages this for me (initialization and execution too), doing it "by hand" on anything complex is probably going to be a nightmare to develop and maintain.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer! One thing that I don't understand is how can I use a method defined in the parent class using inheritance. I was looking into that and it seems as if I need to redefine all the methods (in this case addEvent), that I want the child to use from the parent class. Again, thank you, and sorry if my questions are not very clear as I am new to this.

Comment: Methods are available, but arent visible in the POU in the project tree. If you want to override them from child class, simply add the method and change implementation ( parent methods will be visible in the derived class add method interface)

Comment: You do not need to override (redefine) them if all you want to do is call them and they have an implementation in the parent (i.e. not ABSTRACT). As ziga mentions, they are not visible in the tree, but they are visible in the text editor if you type "." after the instance variable (to program a method call).

Comment: @Fred How would you go about passing an instance down to nested objects? Do you just use a global instance in that case?

Comment: The main idea is, you override FB_Init in the nested function block, add a reference (or pointer) as an argument to that overriden FB_Init, declare a variable of the same type (reference or pointer) as a VAR in the nested function block's body, and perform an assignment of that variable using the FB_Init argument.

Comment: At the site where the nested instance is declared, you will have to add that argument. This is where you would use "THIS" or "THIS^" if what you are passing down is a reference to the parent.

Comment: Obviously, there are other ways to go about doing it. If you have some sort of initialization code, you could call methods on the nested function blocks or set inputs or other variables at initialization time, not using FB_Init at all.  There is no single best way to do it. It all depends on the problem at hand, your constraints, your preferences.